# Динамическая загрузка коллекций сущностей Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp

Приложение ASP NET Core 3.1, использую EF Core 3.1.13.

Есть класс сущности БД, объект которого хранит коллекцию объектов этого же класса подчиненные ему. В свою очередь объекты, которые он хранит у себя  в коллекции, аналогично могут иметь коллекции с другими объектами подчиненные им этого же класса:

```
[Table("groupu")]
    public partial class Groupu
    {
        public Groupu()
        {
            Groupsusers = new HashSet<Groupsusers>();
            InverseGroupParents = new HashSet<Groupu>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("Id_Group")]
        public int IdGroup { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Группа")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(256)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Уровень группы")]
        [Column("Level")]
        public int? Level { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Подчиняется")]
        [Column("Group_Parents_id")]
        public int? GroupParentsId { get; set; }
       
        [DisplayName("Подчиняется")]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupParentsId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Groupu.InverseGroupParents))]
        public virtual Groupu GroupParents { get; set; }
                    
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Groupu.GroupParents))]
        public virtual ICollection<Groupu> InverseGroupParents { get; set; }
    }
```

Задача обойти всех потомков текущей группы до самого низа. Я это делаю с помощью обхода графа в ширину.
Прямые потомки текущего объекта загружаются при запросе на него в БД и в алгоритме я их могу перебрать:

```
Groupu rootGroup = _context.Groupu.Include(g => g.InverseGroupParents).Include(g => g.GroupParents).FirstOrDefault(g => g.IdGroup==id);
```

Проблема в том, что не прямые потомки объекта, т.е. потомки потомков, которые хранятся в коллекциях прямых потомков, уже не загружаются, и я их перебрать уже не могу.

**Как сделать, чтобы коллекции потомков подгружались?**

Алгоритм, который используя для перебора потомков объекта:

```
public List<Groupu> GetAllChildGroupsBFS(Groupu rootGroup, Groupu groupStart, Groupu goal)
        {
            // rootGroup - корневая группа
            // groupStart - начальный потомок
            // goal - пункт назначения, его нет

            // Список всех посещенных потомков
            List<Groupu> childGroupus = new List<Groupu>();

            // инициализируем очередь
            Queue<Groupu> queueGroupu = new Queue<Groupu>();
            // добавляем groupStart в очередь
            queueGroupu.Enqueue(rootGroup);

            while (queueGroupu.Count > 0)
            {
                // удаляем первый (верхний) элемент из очереди
                Groupu directChildgr = queueGroupu.Dequeue();
                //Добавляем посещенную вершину в список потомков
                childGroupus.Add(directChildgr);
                // rootGroup.InverseGroupParents - прямые потомки
                foreach (Groupu childgr in directChildgr.InverseGroupParents)
                {
                    // добавляем его в очередь
                    queueGroupu.Enqueue(childgr);                                          
                }
            }
            // Возвращение списка потомков
            return childGroupus;
        }
```

Comment: Не лепите метки какие попало. ASP - жутко старая технология. Я уверен, что вы её не используете. Метка ASP.NET тоже не имеет отношения к вопросу. Ваш вопрос конкретно по EF Core.

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/). Используйте Explicit loading - метод Load(). Или можно включить ленивую загрузку, но она часто вызывает больше проблем, чем решает и сейчас её мало применяют.

Comment: Чудный микс из BFS и linq, но допустим так... вы правильно понимаете что когда ставите в очередь текущий уровень (```queueGroupu.Enqueue(root```) у вас читается следующий -- но почему-то вы не подумали, что нужно сделать очередной SQL запрос, который будет выгребать последующие уровни. Таких запросов будет столько же, сколько высота дерева/количество уровней. Добавьте аналогичный код в перед ```queueGroupu.Enqueue(childgr);```

Comment: @AK, вот с очередным SQL запросом, который будет выгребать последующие уровни и который будет стоять перед добавление в очередь текущего ```queueGroupu.Enqueue(childgr);``` вроде всё правильно, но как это реализовать? Снова делать аналогичный запрос ```Groupu newChildgr = _context.Groupu.Include(g => g.InverseGroupParents).Include(g => g.GroupParents).FirstOrDefault(g => g.IdGroup==childgr);``` и в очередь добавлять его результат ```queueGroupu.Enqueue(newChildgr);```?

Comment: Так вы определитесь - правильно? Если да, значит реализовано. :) Если как реализовать -- значит неправильно. Ну и посмотрите на свой запрос - там .First стоит, верно? Значит он возвращает верное значение только для root, а как определить несколько элементов на одном уровне? Это ошибка раз. Вторая ошибка - предикат неверный.

Comment: @AK, не понял вас. Здесь ```Groupu rootGroup = _context.Groupu.Include(g => g.InverseGroupParents).Include(g => g.GroupParents).FirstOrDefault(g => g.IdGroup==id);``` я загружаю объект для которого буду искать потомков. Почему здесь .First не верный? Какой предикат не верный?

Comment: Чтобы коллекции потомков подгружались, нужно их подгрузить! Очевидно же, не? Используйте [Explicit Loading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а почему Explicit Loading, а не ```Groupu newChildgr = _context.Groupu.Include(g => g.InverseGroupParents).Include(g => g.GroupParents).FirstOrDefault(g => g.IdGroup==childgr);```?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я кажется понял, мне нужно выполнить только вот эту часть ```context.Entry(childgr)
        .Collection(b => b.InverseGroupParents)
        .Load();```  и он мне должен будет подгрузить коллекции уже по имеющемуся объекту без новой загрузки объекта. Правильно?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ваш способ помог, спасибо, оформите в ответ отмечу

Comment: @AK, спасибо, ваша рекомендация помогла, оформите в ответ я отмечу

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir Простите, но нет. Я не считаю, что задача должна решаться именно таким способом, который я посоветовал в комментариях. Формально вроде как задача решена, вроде как вы взяли хороший алгоритм обхода (мало вообще кто знает про списки смежности и BFS) -- но меня не покидает ощущение, что надо было не ограничиваться полумерами, а сделать качественно иной алгоритм. Какой - пока не знаю, возможно как-нибудь осенит и где-нибудь через полгода напишу полноценный ответ, пока чувствую что стоит ограничиться комментарием.

Comment: У меня есть варианты "выкинуть linq и оформить в виде plain sql", "поменять алгоритм обхода" и даже "поменять структуру базы" (на nested sets например [тынц1](https://habr.com/en/post/263629/) [тынц2](https://habr.com/en/post/46659/)), но я подробно не копал пока ни одно направление. Вы вот лучше пока возьмите и сами напишите свой вариант ответа.

Comment: @AK - на другом [форуме](https://www.sql.ru/forum/1338155/kak-dinamicheski-zagruzhat-kollekciy-sushhnostey-entity-framework) автору тоже разные способы предлагают: CTE, изменить структуру БД, считывать всё в плоский лист и находить связи на клиенте.

Comment: От себя предложу ещё одну статью: [Иерархические структуры и деревья в SQL](https://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2007/03/4199032) - там описаны достоинства и недостатки разных способов.

Comment: Кстати, какая именно СУБД используется? В некоторых СУБД есть специальные средства для работы с иерархическими данными. Например, в Sql Server есть HierarchyId. И его можно использовать в EF Core: [Using SQL Server HierarchyId with Entity Framework Core](https://www.meziantou.net/using-hierarchyid-with-entity-framework-core.htm)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Десять лет не был на sql.ru, какая ностальгия... Советы хорошие, мне понравилось предложение fkthat  уйти в чистый SQL чтобы было проще работать с рекурсивными запросами.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, БД MySQL 8